# How do I check if dovecot is being used?

Tags: rpm, dovecot

I want to remove an old version of MySQL (using rpm) on a RHEL4 server and I found that a dovecot package depends on it. If dovecot is not needed then I could remove that too. How can I determine if dovecot is being used on this server? Are there any log files that would show its past use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) is a daemon that provides access to e-Mail via the POP3 and IMAP protocols.  Is the server providing e-Mail services?

The logging location will depend on your configuration in `/etc/syslog.conf`.  Often the default log location will be `/var/log/maillog`.  Dovecot uses the `mail` logging facility.

If you want to see if dovecot is running, you can run `ps aufx` and look for the dovecot process.

Comment: `ps aufx` does not show dovecot.

Comment: If it is not running, it is fairly safe to say that it is not in use.

Comment: If dovecot was used would "dovecot" appear in /var/log/maillog ?

Comment: It depends on how syslog is configured to direct the `mail` facility.  Potentially.

Comment: Troubleshooting a server that hasn't had much attention in a few years, and suffered a power outage recently. It is hard to say what should or should not be running on it until something breaks. No mentions in 1 month of logs is reassuring enough for me. Thanks for your help!